# Spring Boot App container cannot connect to MySQl container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to containerize my Spring Boot app to work with multiple environments (production and dev). In my dev environment, I use docker-compose to start up an instance of MySQL server which my Spring Boot app is able to connect to when it is running outside a container but when my Spring Boot app is running in a container, it is unable to connect to the MySQL server.

This is the error I get when I run `docker-compose up`.

```
app_1  | 19:48:07.708 ERROR -- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/SessionRepositoryFilterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.session.jdbc.config.annotation.web.http.JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setTransactionManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
app_1  | Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app) for user 'root': Communications link failure
app_1  | 
app_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app_1  | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
app_1  | SQL State  : 08S01
app_1  | Error Code : 0
app_1  | Message    : Communications link failure
app_1  | 
app_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app_1  | 
app_1  | 19:48:07.736  INFO -- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
app_1  | 19:48:07.740  WARN -- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
app_1  | 19:48:07.751  INFO -- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
app_1  | 
app_1  | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
app_1  | 19:48:07.757 ERROR -- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
app_1  | 
app_1  | org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
app_1  |    at com.brand.app.AppApp.main(AppApp.java:28)
app_1  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
app_1  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
app_1  |    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
app_1  |    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
app_1  | Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:125)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:427)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:180)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154)
app_1  |    ... 14 common frames omitted
app_1  | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/SessionRepositoryFilterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.session.jdbc.config.annotation.web.http.JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setTransactionManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
app_1  | Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app) for user 'root': Communications link failure
app_1  | 
app_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app_1  | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
app_1  | SQL State  : 08S01
app_1  | Error Code : 0
app_1  | Message    : Communications link failure
app_1  | 
app_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app_1  | 
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:235)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:226)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:101)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:88)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:261)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54)
app_1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5139)
app_1  |    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
app_1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
app_1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
app_1  |    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
app_1  |    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
app_1  |    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
app_1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
app_1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
app_1  |    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
app_1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
app_1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
app_1  |    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
app_1  |    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
app_1  |    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
app_1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
app_1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
app_1  |    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
app_1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
app_1  |    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
app_1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
app_1  |    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
app_1  |    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:455)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:106)
app_1  |    ... 19 common frames omitted
app_1  | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.session.jdbc.config.annotation.web.http.JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setTransactionManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
app_1  | Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app) for user 'root': Communications link failure
app_1  | 
app_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app_1  | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
app_1  | SQL State  : 08S01
app_1  | Error Code : 0
app_1  | Message    : Communications link failure
app_1  | 
app_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app_1  | 
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:676)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
app_1  |    ... 59 common frames omitted
app_1  | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
app_1  | Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app) for user 'root': Communications link failure
app_1  | 
app_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app_1  | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
app_1  | SQL State  : 08S01
app_1  | Error Code : 0
app_1  | Message    : Communications link failure
app_1  | 
app_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app_1  | 
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:668)
app_1  |    ... 82 common frames omitted
app_1  | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
app_1  | Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app) for user 'root': Communications link failure
app_1  | 
app_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app_1  | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
app_1  | SQL State  : 08S01
app_1  | Error Code : 0
app_1  | Message    : Communications link failure
app_1  | 
app_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app_1  | 
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:224)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1115)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:407)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:341)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:335)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:120)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.setBeanFactory(JpaTransactionManager.java:313)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1765)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
app_1  |    ... 91 common frames omitted
app_1  | Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
app_1  | Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app) for user 'root': Communications link failure
app_1  | 
app_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app_1  | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
app_1  | SQL State  : 08S01
app_1  | Error Code : 0
app_1  | Message    : Communications link failure
app_1  | 
app_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app_1  | 
app_1  |    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:60)
app_1  |    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:72)
app_1  |    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1670)
app_1  |    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1356)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
app_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
app_1  |    ... 108 common frames omitted
app_1  | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
app_1  | 
app_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app_1  |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
app_1  |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
```

Here are some of the files involved.

- `docker-compose.yml` - starts MySQL server and builds using a Dockerfile
- `Dockerfile` - copies necessary files and runs entrypoint.sh
- `entrypoint.sh` - starts the Spring Boot app jar
- `application.properties`
- `application-dev.properties`

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: dev
    image: app:dev
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: app
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql/data
volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

ARG SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=""
ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=${SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE}

COPY target/app.jar /usr/share/
COPY script/entrypoint.sh /bin/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT /bin/entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 5050
```

`entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

sleep 15

exec /usr/bin/java \
     -jar /usr/share/app.jar \
     --spring.profiles.active=${SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE}
```

Any idea why Spring Boot can't connect to MySQL server? Both containers should be on the same default network.

Comment: long time since i used docker compose, but dont you need to expose the port on the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Boot app is trying to connect to `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app` which is fine when the app isn't in a container but when it is in a container, `localhost` is not valid. The name of the MySQL server service is `mysql` (defined in the `docker-compose.yml`), so replacing `localhost` with `mysql` will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For connecting from a docker service to another docker service like a database-service must be set local IP in docker-machine, in this state don't know docker service local IP, we can call with service name instead of service IP. so in the inner docker-machine network for connection to the mysql database or any database as docker service should be changed URL connection to docker service IP or service name

for example,

database URL connection

```
jdbc:mysql://your-mysql-service-name:3306/app
```

docker-compose declare service

```
version: '3.1'
services:

  your-mysql-service-name:
    container_name: your-mysql-service-name
    image: mysql:5.6
    restart: always
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    ports:
    - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "db_name"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "your-password"
```